Arrow keys not recognized in iex or erl
I have recently switched from Ubuntu to Manjaro 24.0. I have come across a strange issue with iex and erl. When I run either of them the arrow keys are not being picked up, I am unable to scroll through the command history or move the cursor left or right. I have figured out that the version of Erlang / OTP matters. Any version prior to 26.1 seems to exhibit this behaviour. Anything after that and the arrow keys work as normal in iex / erl.
I have tried using gnome-terminal, alacritty and urxvt but all of the terminals behave the same. I tried connecting to a server that is running OTP 25.0.2 and Elixir 1.13.4-otp-25 and even when connected to a remote console it still does not recognize the keys.
I have googled around and found the suggestion of adding ERL_AFLAGS='-kernel shell_history enabled' to the environment but this does not fix the issue. Other suggestions were to set my TERM environment to TERM=vt100 or TERM=xterm-256color but this did not help either.
I have exhausted all avenues that I can think of. Has anyone experienced this or have any idea why it might happen? Let me know if I can provide more details that may help.
Thanks

You can test wrapping it with rlwrap which allows to use readline's functions (such as arrow keys) with any program. Try installing rlwarp and then rlwrap iex.

Yea. Tried that and it still doesn’t work unfortunately. Looking at upgrade the code base to solve this :)
